# Magnolia compare and change Property's value logic? (in Java)

Tags: java, content-management-system, magnolia

I'm trying to compare and change a **content property's value** in Magnolia 5.3.2 CE （Community Edition）after the date is smaller than todays date.

I just want to verify my logic here, and will explain some flows below.

> Flows:

Currently I manage to integrate .xls file into magnolia content app. One of the **content property's Name** which being extracted out from the .xls file, I just named it as "Overdue Date" and its **Value** for example "17 October 2014".

After that, there is a **content property** named "Status" which have a **Value** "A". The **content property** "Overdue Date" and "Status" is under the same **Node**. If "Overdue Date" is smaller than today date then will change the "Status" value from "A" into "X"

> I have come out with 2 concepts:

1.) Every time, each of the content app is being created, I will find and search for its **content property's Name** "Overdue Date". And then get its value and compared with **todayDate()**. If "Overdue Date" < **todayDate()**, then change the "Status" into "X" under the same **Node**.

or

2.) I write a function for the **Scheduler Module** to loop and check all the **content property's Name** "Overdue Date" in a **Node**, and then if the "Overdue Date" < **todayDate()**, change the "Status" into "X" under the same **Node**.

If there are any better ideas, please let me know...thanks.
**If anythings not clear, I will add-ons later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you use that property for? Is it just to display status in workbench? Why don't you write column formatter that would just calculate status dynamically instead of having update property in repo?

Comment: I need one of the property value to do some comparison and then update another property value under the same child Node, if I calculate status dynamically with column formatter, will the performance would being affected?

Comment: Value is always calculated only for rows that are currently displayed - that is about 20-30 rows max. I don't think you will see any performance impact with that. 
But if you need this value in other places then just workbench then go ahead and store it, it just seems like lot of work for little benefit. Even if you need to for example filter by all over due tasks, you can run JCR query that would return you all records that are after today(), etc.

Comment: wow, I never thought about that...That is really helpful, I will rebuild my theory first before I go to coding...